# How can I refer to an uninitialized button on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, button

I am new to Qt and C++, so I apologize if this is a stupid question but I haven't found any answers online. I am working on this game where every time I press a button I need to refer to the button that was pressed before this one and the current one too.  I created a button that has the sole purpose of containing the button that was pressed before this one, so, the problem is that the first time I press a button there is no last pressed button, so when I try to use it, it gives me this error:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Here is how I create the button:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QPushButton *lastPressed;
...
```

And then I have 50 buttons with this same code but changing a variable and, of course, the button that is changing icon:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Client client;
    string received = client.startClient(1);
    vector<string> commands = this->getWords(received);

    if (commands[0] == "TipoA"){
        ui->pushButton->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/TipoA.png"));
    }
    if (commands[0] == "TipoB"){
        ui->pushButton->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/TipoB.png"));
    }
    if (commands[0] == "TipoC"){
        ui->pushButton->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/TipoC.png"));
    }
    if (commands[0] == "TipoD"){
        ui->pushButton->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/TipoD.png"));
    }
    if (commands[0] == "TipoE") {
        ui->pushButton->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/TipoE.png"));
    }
    sleep(5);

    if(commands[1] != "0"){
        ui->pushButton->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/dun.png"));
        this->lastPressed->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/dun.png"));
    }else{
        ui->pushButton->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/icon.png"));
        this->lastPressed->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/icon.png"));
    }
    this->lastPressed = ui->pushButton;
}
```

So I wanted to know if there is a way I can refer to lastPressed when it hasn't been initialized, so I can make an "if" kind of like:

```
if(this->lastPressed != null){
this->lastPressed->setIcon(
                QIcon("/home/alejandra/build-Project01_memoryGame-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_GCC_64bit-Debug/Resources/icon.png"));
}
```

Comment: If you dereference a nullpointer you will have some undefined behavior. You should have that check for a `nullptr` (I think `null` is somewhat worse than `nullptr`, but someone more qualified can go into that). After the check just have a default case for the zeroth button so to speak. You can also just initialise a phantom button at the start which is never pressed and has slightly different logic, but that is essentially just a default case.

Comment: Thank you!! I don't know if what you meant with phantom button was creating another button like lastPressed and then making this one equal to that one so I can compare them, but it worked!

Comment: `null` is not a thing in C++ as far as I know - there is `NULL`, an "old" constant for the value 0, or `nullptr`, introduced with C++11, which is the proper value for a pointer pointing to "nothing". So you want to use `nullptr` here to initialize lastPressed, and also check for it (or `if (this->lastPressed) {` also would work, since a pointer is converted to a boolean automatically -> true if set to something else than `nullptr`)

Comment: You seem to have some confusion, `lastPressed` isn't a button it's a pointer to a button object, you haven't created a button you've created a pointer. I'm guessing your problem is that you haven't initialised `lastPressed` to `nullptr`